# SQL data type mismatch for integers and dates

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am using MSquery and have the following sql query:

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA, `Sheet1$`.colB, 
Switch(
colA = '1.0', 'A1',
colA = '2.0', 'A2',
colA = '3.0', 'C1',
colA = '4.0', 'C2'

)AS colG


FROM (

SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA, `Sheet1$`.colB
FROM `Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
UNION ALL
SELECT `Sheet2$`.colC, `Sheet2$`.colD
FROM `Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`
) t;
```

I am getting an error message: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. I think it has something to do with the fact that I used single quotes around the numbers in the switch statement.

I have two tables and am appending them. An extra column is then added and a different message should be added depending on the value in column A for each row. This query works when I have column A as text, however when I try it for numbers or dates I get the error message. What do I need to use instead of single quotes for numbers and dates? Is it ok to use single quotes for the message that will be displayed?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Try `[Sheet1$]` instead of the backticks.

Comment: Is `colA` currently text or is it numeric?

Comment: colA is numeric. For testing I origionally used text and it worked as I wanted but when I change it to numbers I get the error message. As well as numbers I would also like to know how I would use dates.

Answer (score 1):

Change `colA` to a numeric type and then use the following query:

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA,
        `Sheet1$`.colB, 
       SWITCH (
           colA = 1.0, 'A1',
           colA = 2.0, 'A2',
           colA = 3.0, 'C1',
           colA = 4.0, 'C2'
       ) AS colG
FROM
(
SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA,
       `Sheet1$`.colB
FROM `Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
UNION ALL
SELECT `Sheet2$`.colC,
       `Sheet2$`.colD
FROM `Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for numbers. Do you know what I would do if colA was a date instead of numeric?

Comment: Use `colA = #2016-08-22#, 'A1'` inside your `SWITCH` function.